# Why does my logo from Logomaker look bad?

Tags: logo, software-recommendation, pixelation

I am using the website [logomaker.com](http://www.logomaker.com/) to create a company logo. When it is enlarged though it gets fuzzy (pixelated). How can I fix this in Logomaker?

Is there a better service for a non-designer to use to make a logo with minimum effort?

Comment: For only $49.00 you can get your clipart in a high res file.

Comment: we arent here to help you create software, we are a Q&A website for people that can show effort and the professionals that visit the site try to assist them.  So to your comment, "create a software like that logo maker and gives the user to a proper kind of logo with no errors" you haven't identified the errors in your question.  The software did what you wanted it to.  You also tagged this with three software applications so Im lost in what your intention is.  All I can assume is you want an SVG like Yorik has pointed out, either way no one understands what you want language barrier or not.

Comment: "Logo Maker" is specifically designed to be used by non-professionals in order for them to save money and throw a few clip art pieces together with some text. If you *really* are interested in creating logos at a higher level you can use any of the software tags you used - Photoshop, Illustrator, and to a lesser degree InDesign. You can't "fix" Logo Maker to be better than it is. As @Ryan pointed out, you can spend more money to get high resolution versions of the clip art Logo Maker uses, but that's the best you are going to get with that application.

Comment: so adobe illustrator is the only software to make a logo ?

Comment: no there are tons of software applications that can make a logo..  I would suggest googling or using our search bar at the top for the many questions on the topic.

Comment: **Nothing** is going to be as simple, drag and drop as Logo Maker is. Practically **any** other software is going to entail *learning* to use the software. If you want easy drag and drop.. I think PowerPoint would be the closest to Logo Maker. But it wouldn't necessarily be *better* than Logo Maker.

Comment: what you think  a software like logo maker is better or adobe illustrator .....??? if anyone is non-professional ...

Comment: I think you need to spend sometime and research what software can do what and research our questions in regards to an individual's case by case issue.  We have a lovely selection of questions you could browse through at the top right.  I suggest this because you have shown no effort and it would seem you're wanting a quick solution and that's not what we are here for.

Comment: Because you get what you pay for.

Comment: On a serious note, realize that it's not the software that makes a logo good. It's the design skill of the person running the software. By all means, if this is something you want to try, go for it. We'll be glad to help. But before you fork over a lot of time and money for software, consider instead hiring a designer if your ultimate goal is to simply have a decent logo.

Answer (score 0):

as a suggestion, use inkscape. Download it, import the picture you got from Logomaker in it's original size. Then trace bitmap as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzmdqwFpxp8

Use the color option (instead of threshold as shown in vid), with remove background checked. Pick as many scans as you have colors, plus 1 for background. Then blow it up as big as you need it using scale, and export bitmap, it will always export perfectly. Sounds complex, but a bit more reading and an hour learning you'll have what you're looking for.